# OpenAI API error: "Module 'openai' has no exported member 'Configuration'. Did you mean to use 'import Configuration from "openai"' instead"?

Tags: typescript, openai-api, chatgpt-api

In my `route.ts` where I call the OpenAI API, I get the following error:

> Module 'openai' has no exported member 'Configuration'. Did you mean
> to use 'import Configuration from "openai" instead?

I believe I need to use the updated OpenAI Node.js library. How do I implement the updated version in the following code?

```js
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export async function POST(
    req: Request
){
    try {
        const { userId } = auth();
        const body = await req.json();
        const { messages } = body;

        if (!userId) {
            return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
        }

        if (!configuration.apiKey) {
            return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key not configured", { status: 500 });
        }

        if (!messages){
            return new NextResponse("Messages are required", {status: 400 });
        }

        const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages

        });

        return NextResponse.json(response.data.choices[0].message);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]", error);
        return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The OpenAI Node.js SDK >=`v4` has a lot of breaking changes.** There are 2 problems in your code, but you don't know about the second one because the error was thrown before you got there.

**Problem 1: Incorrect initialization**

Change this...

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

...to this.

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'],
});
```

**Problem 2: Incorrect method name**

Change this...

```
const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages
});
```

...to this.

```
const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages
});
```